# Are loops counted twice in Feynman diagrams?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, feynman-diagrams, propagator

Consider the 2 point function in $\phi^4$ theory which is given as something proportional to
$$\int D(x-z) D(y-z) D(z-z) d^4 z,$$
where $D$ is the propagator. The corresponding Feynman diagram looks like this:

[image]

I understand where this comes from, but one thing I cannot figure out is why the vertex at $z$ is not connected to 4 propagators. Since the interaction term in the Lagrangian is $\phi^4$ shouldn't every vertex have 4 lines going into/out of it? Here there are only 3: $D(x-y)$, $D(z-y)$, and the loop $D(z-z)$. Are such loops counted twice? If so, why?

Answer (score 3):

Propagators correspond to line segments; since there are three line segments, there are three propagators. Two 'offshoots' of the vertex are covered by one propagator (the loop), but you'll notice that $z$ still appears four times in the integral, so the $\phi^4$ interaction is satisfied.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still a little confused on how the $\phi^4$ interaction is satisfied. At this vertex $z$ interacts with $x$, $y$, and itself. So how do we get the fourth interaction?

Comment: You don't need four propagators; you just need four connections to the vertex. If you want to imagine drawing this: I go from $z$ to $x$, getting a factor of $D(x-z)$; I go from $z$ to $y$, getting a factor of $D(y-z)$; and I go from $z$ and *back* to $z$, getting a factor of $D(z-z)$. The interaction with itself counts twice, as it is both the interactor and interactee, but since there is only *one* interaction, we have one propagator. Another way of looking at it: the loop attaches two legs to the vertex (accounting for two out of four), but there is only one loop, so only one propagator.

Comment: Thanks, I understand why there are only three propagators now. However I still don't understand why the $z$ self-interaction counts as two interactions. Would you be able to elaborate on that?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the self-loop propagator $D(z-z)$ in OP's Feynman diagram occupies 2 of the 4 legs of the 4-vertex. It is also responsible for a [symmetry factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram#Symmetry_factors) $S=2$ that the diagram should be divided with.

Comment: How does the self-loop occupy 2 legs? I guess we count each loop twice when counting the total number of legs?